# How to get prices with ProductEntity?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I created my own Entity called "MyProductEntity" (and also Definition/Collection) which has a relation to some Product (eg. a product is linked with another product)

The problem is that MyProductEntity->connectedProduct doesn't contain prices (eg. calculatedPrices). Does anyone know how to load the prices? I read somewhere that I should use SalesChannelProductEntity instead of ProductEntity? But I am not sure how? Any hints?

Here are (I hope) the relevant parts from my code:

```php
class MyProductEntity extends Entity
{
    protected string $productId;
    protected string $productVersionId;
    protected ProductEntity $product;

    protected string $connectedProductId;
    protected string $connectedProductVersionId;
    protected ProductEntity $connectedProduct;
    //I tried to use here "SalesChannelProductEntity" instead of "ProductEntity"
    //...
    //other properties
}
```

in some subscriber: (eg.: for ProductPageLoadedEvent::class) I load MyProductEntity like this:

```php
public function getMyProducts(ProductPageLoadedEvent $event): array
{

    $page = $event->getPage();
    $salesChannelContext = $event->getSalesChannelContext();
    $product = $page->getProduct();

    $criteria = new Criteria();
    $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('productId', $product->getId()));
    $criteria->addAssociation('connectedProduct');

    $myProducts = $this->myProductRepository->search($criteria, $salesChannelContext);
    //$this->myProductRepository = defined via services.xml / in constructor:
    // EntityRepository $myProductRepository
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already found out the field `calculatedPrices` and similar are exclusive to the [`SalesChannelProductDefinition`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/027efc5bd32b6e91475784e874f6157fc8a76fe5/src/Core/Content/Product/SalesChannel/SalesChannelProductDefinition.php) and `SalesChannelProductEntity`. You could simply create your own sales channel definition in addition to the regular definition:

```php
class SalesChannelMyProductDefinition extends MyProductDefinition implements SalesChannelDefinitionInterface
```

```xml
<service id="Foo\MyPlugin\SalesChannel\SalesChannelMyProductDefinition">
    <tag name="shopware.sales_channel.entity.definition"/>
</service>
```

Then use the repository of your new sales channel definition:

```php
$myProduct = $this->getContainer()->get('sales_channel.my_product.repository')
    ->search($criteria, $salesChannelContext)->first();
// should then be an instance of SalesChannelProductEntity
$salesChannelProduct = $myproduct->getConnectedProduct();
```